# PYQTGraph application slows down when mouse moves over application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have a multi-threaded (via pyqt) application which plots realtime data (data is processed in the second thread and passed to the gui thread to plot via a pyqt-signal). If I place the mouse over the application it continues to run at full speed (as measured by the time difference between calls to `app.processEvents()`). As soon as I begin moving the mouse, the update rate slows to a crawl, increasing again when I stop moving the mouse.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this/debug the issue?

The code is quite lengthy and complex so I'd rather not post it here. Thanks!

Comment: Might seem obvious, but have you checked if there are any mouseMoveEvent event handlers active?

Comment: I haven't explicitly defined any. How would I go about finding any defaults?

Comment: I think it would be good to see your code. Having calling `processEvents` in your code is not ideal, so that may be part of your problem

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you have items in the scene that accept their own mouse input, but it's difficult to say without seeing code. In particular, be wary of complex plot lines that are made clickable--it is very expensive to compute the intersection of the mouse cursor with such complex shapes.

The best (some would say only) way to solve performance issues is to profile your application: run `python -m cProfile -s cumulative your_script.py` once without moving the mouse, and again with mouse movement (be sure to spend plenty of time moving the mouse), and then compare the outputs to see where the interpreter is spending all of its time.

Comment: Thanks,  I can see the `mouseMoveEvent` call from GraphicsView.py and GraphicsScene.py in the profiled code (3rd and 4th in the cumulative profile after the <module> and {build-in method exec_}. I have a  `GraphicsLayoutWidget` object using `addPlot` to create the plots. I can't immediately see what is calling the `mouseMoveEvent` though.

Comment: Whilst putting together a slimmed down coding of my python script to demonstrate the problem I found that it was caused by the second data thread `run()` call. I've no idea why this was slowing the whole program down when the mouse moved, or why it was firing a `mouseMoveEvent`. I'll post the slimed code below anyway

Comment: We should find a different place to discuss that code, but I'll drop a couple of hints: 1) Your thread is consuming a lot of CPU and constantly hanging up the GIL. You should expect performance to deteriorate in that case.2) Just because code is defined as a method of a QThread does not mean the code must be running in another thread. In your case, the second thread does nothing but waste CPU cycles--the data generation actually occurs in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this; I've moved on from the QThread definition to a QObject, moveToThread code structure.